# Plot "Dotplot" (stacked points)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I know there is a `dotchart` function in R for making a dotplot but it doesn't give me quite what I am looking for. I want the plot style to resemble something closer to the following:

```
c(8, 12, 10, 16, 6, 25, 21, 15,17, 5, 26, 21, 29, 8, 10, 21, 10, 17, 15, 13)
```

[image]

Is there anything in R that can do this?

Comment: `stripchart`...

Comment: In base, `plot(table(rep(c(1,4,5), 1:3)))` maybe, though it doesn't have discrete dots for each count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's literally `ggplot2` geom called "dotplot" :-)

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(8, 12, 10, 16, 6, 25, 21, 15, 
                       17, 5, 26, 21, 29, 8, 10, 21, 
                       10, 17, 15, 13))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(a)) + 
    geom_dotplot()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, I googled around and this never came up. Should have known better to rely on ggplot. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`plotrix` package has a function for it

```
x = c(8, 12, 10, 16, 6, 25, 21, 15, 17, 5, 26, 21, 29, 8, 10, 21, 10, 17, 15, 13)
plotrix::dotplot.mtb(x)
```

[image]